# Linking to X11 under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, x11

I have a Hello, World C program for X11 downloaded from somewhere. It compiles, but doesn't link properly.

The 32-bit Ubuntu version runs in VM VirtualBox under Windows 7. The compile and link command I use (one of many variations I tried) is:

```
gcc -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lX11 hellowin.c
```

Apparently, that is the correct location, as 'locate libX11' gives me:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.a
```

amongst other such files (mostly .so ones). The errors I get are like this:

```
....undefined reference to 'XOpenDisplay'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: It now works if I leave out -L and move the -l to after the file as suggested. Eg:

```
gcc hellowin.o -lX11
```

or specifying the library directly, but this only works with .so, not .a:

```
gcc hellowin.o /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so
```

(The build instructions with the Hello, World source used -L and -l, and they were both placed before the object file name.)

Comment: First, remove that `-L` flag (if it was needed, the linker would tell you that it cannot find libX11). Second, order matters: if A depends on B, A should be before B on the command line.

Comment: So the library being reference goes after the reference? Seems unintuive but that seems to be the case. (How do you insert a newline in this thing, without accidentally posting?!) I solved it now but I will show how in an edit to my OP as that is easier.

Answer (score 1):

Order of arguments to `gcc` and linking matters a big lot (compiler options, sources files, object files, libraries from high-level to low-level ones):

```
gcc -Wall -g  hellowin.c  -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lX11 -o hellowin
```

then try

```
./hellowin
```

you might need to use the debugger with

```
gdb ./hellowin
```

Answer (score 0):

I compiled a version of "Hello world" from rosettacode and I have not recieved any errors. Try using another version of Ubuntu (mine was an old version from VritualBox: Ubuntu 12). I was using Windows 10. (Although I think this should not matter).
Maybe you forgot to include one of the libraries. 
If anything does not work, please give us some of the code that is not running.
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Window_creation/X11#Xlib